# Why are dynamically created objects twice as many bits apart as the object's size?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

I have code written to create a linked list of dynamically created objects:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X {
  int i;
  X* x;
};

void birth(X* head, int quant){
  X* x = head;
  for(int i=0;i<quant-1;i++){
    x->i = i+1;
    x->x = new X;
    x = x->x;
  }
  x->i = quant;
  x->x = 0;
}

void kill(X* x){
  X* next;
  while(1==1){
    cout << x->i << endl;
    cout << (long)x << endl;
    next = x->x;
    delete x;
    if(next == 0){
      break;
    } else {
      x = next;
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  cout << (long)sizeof(X) << endl;
  X* x = new X;
  birth(x, 10);
  kill(x);
  return 0;
}
```

Which seems to be working, except for the fact that when you look at the addresses of each of the objects...

```
16
1
38768656
2
38768688
3
38768720
4
38768752
5
38768784
6
38768816
7
38768848
8
38768880
9
38768912
10
38768944
```

They seem to be created 32 bits apart despite the size of X being only 16 bits. Is there an issue with how I am creating the objects, or is this just a consequence of how dynamic allocation works?

Comment: Which compiler and platform are you on? Also, I think you mean 16 bytes, not bits...

Comment: You are concerned about an implementation detail. It may change anytime. In particular, there could be several reasons for the extra space: memory alignment, internal bookkeeping of the code that manages the heap etc.

Comment: Why should the `X`'s be allocated in a contiguous manner? You're creating them on the heap with `new`, their address could be anything.

Comment: C or C++?  You've tagged your question with C, but you've written C++ code.

Comment: My guess is that your struct technically is 32 bytes because you have a recursive pointer which points to a 16-byte integer. You also dereference that second integer which could be the reason that the objects are created 32 bits apart. Have you tried creating the object without the pointer? Comment it out and code pertaining to it and see what the result is!

Comment: @AndrewHenle, that's my bad. I failed to see cout and new in the end, and just seen the list implementation in C, so I edited the tags. I take full responsibility for this.

Comment: @Poriferous, what a nonsese...

Answer (score 7):

The reason is stated in **7.22.3 Memory management functions** of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls to
>   the `aligned_alloc`, `calloc`, `malloc`,  and `realloc` functions is
>   unspecified.   The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
>   suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
>   of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to
>   access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
>   allocated

Since the memory must be "suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement", memory returned by `malloc` *et al* tends to start on distinct, platform-dependent multiples - usually 8- or 16-byte boundaries.

And because `new` is usually implemented with `malloc`, this applies to C++ `new` also.

Comment: So are we seeing 32-byte boundaries in the question?  Or is it 16 byte boundaries with some record keeping in the memory manager?

Comment: @ebyrob The OP hasn't specified the platform in question, so any answer would just be a guess.  But I'd guess it's 16-byte boundaries with 16-byte overhead, or perhaps 8-byte boundaries that show up at 16-byte boundaries because of 16 bytes of overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Addresses of allocated memory blocks are controlled by the heap manager. Only the heap manager's interface is defined (`new`/`delete`, `malloc`/`free`), not its implementation. The application has to accept the provided addresses and work with them.

In other words, it is theoretically possible to implement a heap manager that allocates memory blocks at random-like addresses. The application, however, has to work equally well also in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The [`new` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) does not guarantee contiguous allocation. Here is a more convincing example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; ++i)
        std::cout << std::hex << new int() << std::endl;
}
```

Output on a 64bit CPU:

```
0x22cac20
0x22cac40
0x22cac60
0x22cac80
...
0x22cafe0
0x22cb000
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fe96d5c1f6383ca)</kbd>

Comment: So are you saying a 32-byte alignment is common on 64-bit CPU?

Comment: No i'm not. The way `new` allocates memory is completely unspecified. I'm just showing a more [mcve] example. I was about to quote the standard but Andrew Henle was faster and earned my upvote.

Comment: The example seems to counter what you're saying.  It does indeed allocate memory consistently and predictably.  (for this simple test)

Comment: @ebyrob but not contiguously. `sizeof(int)` is not `0x20`.

Comment: 0x20 is 32 bytes.  If that's the alignment then the heap may never be able to use the pointers in-between these values.  In which case they are contiguous.  Just larger than requested.

Comment: @ebyrob Contiguous generally means that you can play with pointer arithmetic. Imagine `int* a = new int(); int* b = new int();`. If `new` allocated memory like `new[]` does, `a + 1 == b` would be true. This is not the case here. The memory is **not** allocated contiguously.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99316/discussion-between-ebyrob-and-ysc).

Comment: @ebyrob I think you'll find that program demonstrated a 32-byte minimum allocation (including overhead) **NOT** 32-byte alignment.  Try declaring `struct foo { int b[10]; };` and then using `new foo` instead.  I expect you'll see 48 byte total (40 byte content, 8 byte overhead, 16 byte alignment).

Answer (score 1):

You are working in an environment with 8 bytes of allocation overhead and minimum dynamic memory alignment of 16 bytes.  So each 16 byte allocation has 8 bytes of allocation overhead and 8 bytes of alignment padding.

If you try again with a 24 byte object (making sure `sizeof` really is 24 not 32) you will find only 8 bytes of overhead and not an additional 8 bytes of alignment padding.

There is a minimum size (including overhead) of 32 bytes.  So if you try with a tiny object, you get a total of 32, not 16.  If you try with a 40 byte object, you get a total of 48 demonstrating the lack of 32 byte alignment.

That is all specific to the environment in which you are running.  The C++ standard allows for a much wider range of possible behavior.

The 8 bytes immediately preceding the 16-byte aligned chunk returned by the allocator must hold the size of the allocation plus at least one status bit indicating whether the **previous** chunk is free.  That is the minimum overhead a 64-bit allocator needs and while the chunk is in use it is all the overhead needed.  But once a chunk is free, there is significant overhead at the beginning of the chunk to support consolidating adjacent free chunks and to support quickly finding a good size free chunk for new allocations.  That overhead wouldn't fit if the total were just 16 bytes.